# Java if statement fails when comparing two strings

Tags: java, if-statement, server, client

this issue has been wrecking my head all night and I can't seem to figure out why it won't work.
So I'm running a client/server program, and having the client enter a certain string through JOptionPane,and then sending it to server. The server has an array of strings and it checks if the string received from client is equal to one of the strings in the array. However, the comparison appears to be failing. I'd be delighted if anyone can tell me why I'm encountering this issue.

Below is the code for my server, Where the if statement is failing inside the for loop,  and the array (usrs):

```
String [] usrs = {"Hassan","Jimmy","Bob","Kevin"};

DatagramSocket skt = null;

try {
    skt = new DatagramSocket(2002);
    byte [] buffer = new byte [1000];
    String okay = "OK";
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Inside loop");
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            skt.receive(request);
        String userName = (new String(request.getData()));
        System.out.println(userName);
        for (int i=0; i < usrs.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println(usrs[i]);
            //if user exists in list of verified users,we send the RSA encrypted AES Key using that user's public key which we receive from the user
            if (userName.equals(usrs[i])) { 
                System.out.println("Inside If");
                byte [] okayMsg = okay.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(okayMsg,okayMsg.length,request.getAddress(),request.getPort());
                skt.send(reply);
                skt.close();
            }            
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for the Client:

```
try {     
    skt = new DatagramSocket();
    String userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your username");
    byte [] b = userName.getBytes();
    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    int serverSocket = 2002;
    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(b,b.length,host,serverSocket);

    skt.send(request);

    byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];

    DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

    skt.receive(reply);

    String replyData = new String(reply.getData());
    System.out.println(replyData);

    skt.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
};
```

And here is the output:

```
 Inside loop
 Hassan
 Hassan
 Jimmy
 Bob
 Kevin
 Inside loop
```

Comment: Can you just ensure that there are no trailing spaces or other invisible characters?

Comment: From the output it appears to have passed for string "Hassan"??

Comment: No, it hasn't! it has not gone in "Inside if" block

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Can you try using the String.equalsIgnoreCase method

Comment: Can you just check if the length of the userName string and the strings in usrs is equal too? That would remove the possibility of trailing characters

Comment: I did that..didn't fix it :( @AnupamSaini

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram yes you are correct my bad.

Comment: @HassanAli Can you print the length of the data received, i.e request.getLength() and share the results here

Comment: @AnupamSaini turns out it was because my buffer size was 1000 so it set my string length through to buffer to be 1000 as well. thanks a lot!

Comment: can you try this inside if, userName.equals(usrs[i].trim())

Comment: @RaghuNagaraju No, don't trim - what if the string you are looking for actually starts/ends with whitespace characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently printing the `request.getLength()`  solves the issue.
The response received was padded to be the size of response buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the length of the `DatagramPacket` when constructing `replyData`:

```
String replyData = new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength());
```

Otherwise it is assumed that the entire array returned by `reply.getData()` contains string data, which is not necessarily the case, as you found.

It is also sensible to use explicit character encoding, in order that you don't get strange behaviour owing to mismatched default character encodings on the client and server JVMs:

```
byte [] b = userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and

```
String replyData = new String(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```